# where is the product alert link of a product grouped?

Tags: product, alert

I just can see this link at simple products
I need this feature at grouped products

Answer (score 1):

The product alert notify visitor when product gets back to stock. Grouped product contains of products which are not mandatory for purchase. Visitor can purchase any combination of products included into a grouped product. Thus it's impossible to notify visitor as nobody knows which set of products he will need and if it is back in stock.